# DIR_MODE has no effect on domain-joined user profiles in /home

Tags: permissions, home-directory, adduser

In **/etc/adduser.conf** I edited it to be **DIR_MODE=0750** so all home directories are not world readable. However, this only seems to effect LOCAL users in the **/home** directory.

I have since joined my computer to a Windows domain and when I log in using a domain user it creates home folders in **/home** along with all the local users.

The **DIR_MODE=0750** does not seem to apply to these folders that are created on the fly as domain users log in.

Any ideas how to get **DIR_MODE** in **adduser.conf** to apply to domain user's home folders?

Comment: adduser.conf is adduser, addgroup, deluser and delgroup file configuration. Could you add more information about 'I have since joined my computer to a Windows domain and when I log in using a domain user it creates home folders in /home along with all the local users'? Are you using LDAP server for this or samba active directory?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and info. I'm using Powerbroker Identity Services (PBIS Open 8.0.1 - Stable Release). Sorry, but knowing this I am still not exactly sure how to answer your question about whether if it's LDAP server or samba active directory.

Comment: I found this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SambaActiveDirectoryDomainIntegrationScript). But I guess that there are better solution. Did you try Powerbroker Identity Services documentation?

Comment: I did look at their documentation but couldn't find anything relating to this. I read [THIS](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Ubuntu/2014-06/msg00334.html) which said that changing UMASK from 22 to 27 is the equivalent of 0750 but that didnt' work either. I apologize if there are readers shaking their head at me. I'm a noob :\

Comment: I just found a config option "HomeDirUmask '022'" in the Powerbroker config file. I will change to 027 and report back.

Comment: After changing HomeDirUmask to 27 and also another value I found in the Powerbroker config (Local_HomeDirUmask) to 27, newly created folders from domain users are NOT world readable and I cannot browse to their home folders ONLY from local users. I am still able to browse around all home folders from any domain user I log in with, whether they're in the sudoers file or not. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

I changed both 027 values in /opt/pbis/bin/config to 077 and also have UMASK set to 077 in /etc/login.defs and DIR_MODE in /etc/adduser.conf set to 0750 and EVERYTHING WORKS the way I want. Only the user that creates their home folder (and root of course) has access to the home folder. Awesome!

Comment: Yes! Good. Here is umask manual [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/umask.2.html).